# calling action from button onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I am new on mvc programming. I have two labels, two textboxes and one button and I have to use devexpress tools. It is like login form. I want to call an actionresult from a controller class when I click the button. How can I do that if it is possible?

That's my button

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Giriş" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click"  Theme="Moderno" EnableTheming="True"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

and that's my button click event

```
<script runat="server">

protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
</script>
```

and these are in Index.aspx page.

Comment: This is not asp.net mvc. This is asp.net web forms. However, I can't get what you want. You have a button and you have bind an event handler for the OnClick event. Ok, what's the problem?

Comment: Christos, I have HomeController.cs and an actionresult in it. I want to call that actionresult from button onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your asking, but I'll attempt to clarify.

```
// Model View Controller:
<form action="/Home/Validate" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username" required />
     <input type="text" name="password" required />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

That would be in your code, then you hit the button which will submit your form and point to your `Validate Controller`.  Which would look like:

```
public ActionResult Validate(string username, string password)
{
     // Do Stuff, then call your next view and pass model.
     return RedirectToAction("Account");
}
```

**Important:** In Model View Controller you don't call button clicks, you call Controllers.  So you would point your destination to a Controller method (example):

```
<a href="/Home/Validate">Validate</a>
<input type="button" onclick="/Home/Validate" />
```

- *Home* - will reference the *Controller*
- *Validate* - will reference the method within the Controller.

---

Your code is from the realm of an Web-Forms, if it is all server side code without custom JavaScript then you may be able to simply do:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="updAccount" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         // Your button, textbox for Submit (Alleviates Postback).
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

That would be the simpler of the two Web-Forms approach.  However, you could indeed use jQuery or JavaScript to accomplish this as well.